# PHP - Persistant connections, too many connections

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a website where I have around 700 - 1000 users online at all times. Lately I have experienced that my website is getting very slow. There seems to be some sort of bottleneck.

My current setup is I have an `index.php` page, which handles all my subpages. The design is like this:

```
include_once($settings['incpath'].'_ify_database.php');

    //Define the extra page levels. 
    $i = (isset($_GET['i']) ? inputFilter($_GET['i']) : 'h');
    $xp = (isset($_GET['p']) ? inputFilter($_GET['p']) : null);
    $xpp = (isset($_GET['n']) ? inputFilter($_GET['n']) : null);    

    switch($i){
        case 'h': // Home
            include($settings['themespath'].$config['active_theme'].'/indexheader.php');
            include($settings['pagepath'].'home.php');
            include($settings['themespath'].$config['active_theme'].'/indexfooter.php');
        break;
     }
```

This is how I connect to the database (`_ify_database.php`):

```
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $database['host'] . ";dbname=" . $database['db'];
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $database['user'], $database['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT));     
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT); // <== add this line
    }
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

As you can see, I've set the persistent connection to `false`:

```
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
```

If I enable it to `TRUE` I see a good increase in the load time, but after some time I get `Too Many Connections` error.

What am I doing wrong? If there is 500 people on the website it's fast. If there is 900-1000 it double it's load time.

Comment: You should monitor MySQL and verity if those connections are actually being used, or just idle. In the fist case, it might be worth increasing the limit.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Many of these visitors are just getting redirected to my site, and is there for maybe 0 - 2 mins. How can I prevent these connections being idle?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "getting redirected"... I haven't tried again with recent PHP versions but I've had bad experiences in the past with the MySQL driver not being able to reuse connections and opening new ones unnecessarily—a `show processlist` query would show most connections as "Sleep".

Comment: You didn't specify how you serve PHP - via Apache and `mod_php` or are you using `php-fpm` - this is crucial to your problem because we can identify how many connections there really are and whether SQL is the bottleneck. Don't solve anything until you are 100% certain where to look. Also, is everything located on one physical machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

limit the max number of persistent connections from php, or increase the limit in mysql.. try

```
ini_set('mysql.max_persistent','500');
ini_set('mysqli.max_persistent','500');
```

and found this in the mysql docs, seems related: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html